# Table resizing adds the word "height" and caption isn't formatting properly

Tags: tables, wlscirep

I have a table that's kind of long that I'm trying to format, but when I use `\resizebox`, the pdf won't render (I'm using Overleaf). I tried `{adjustbox}`, which worked, but for some reason inserted the word "height" at the end of the table. And even before trying either of those options, the caption didn't format properly. It's half in italics with no spaces and goes off the page in a single line.

Here's the code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllllllll}

\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\rho\\ (g/cm^3)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}E_1\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}E_2\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & $\nu$_1_2 & $\nu$_2_3 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}G_1_2\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}G_2_3\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$\sigma$_1_,_T\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$\sigma$_1_,_C\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$\sigma$_2_,_T\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$\sigma$_2_,_C\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$\tau$_1_2\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$\tau$_2_3\\ (MPa)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}U_1_,_T\\ (N/mm)\end{tabular} \\ \hline
1.22                                                 & 140000                                             & 9000                                               & 0.28 & 0.49 & 5400                                                & 5400                                                & 2570                                                  & 1570                                                  & 63.4                                                  & 266                                                   & 95.8                                                 & 95.8                                                 & 12.5                                                  \\
                                                     &                                                    &                                                    &      &      &                                                     &                                                     &                                                       &                                                       &                                                       &                                                       &                                                      &                                                      &                                                       \\
                                                     &                                                    &                                                    &      &      &                                                     &                                                     &                                                       &                                                       &                                                       &                                                       &                                                      &                                                      &                                                      
\end{tabular}
\caption{Mechanical property of the carbon fiber/epoxy composite material. Variable $\rho$ is mass density, E_i, $\nu$_ij, G_ij, and $\tau$_ij are Young's modulus, Poisson's ratio, shear modulus, and shear strength in corresponding directions; $\sigma$_i,T/C and U_i,T/C are tensile/compressive strengths in the corresponding directions \cite{liu2014failure}}
\end{table}
```

And here are all the packages I'm using

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[font=normal,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
%\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
```

These are all the errors that come up at the caption:

```
Improper \spacefactor.
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
Missing $ inserted.
You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
Missing } inserted.
Missing number, treated as zero.
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
Overfull \hbox (333.14093pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 145--145
Missing number, treated as zero.
Missing \endgroup inserted.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a compilable short tex code resulting in your errors! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: You can't put \caption inside a \hbox.  You need a minipage, \parbox or \vbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Where can be find documjentclass `wlscirep`?
- Your column headers are big mess. What you expect to het from `$\nu$_1_2`? I guess that should be written as `$\nu_{1_2}$` or `$\nu_{12}$`. Clarify please.
- instead of `\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} ...\end{tabular}` try to use `\makecell[l]{...}`. At least code is shorter and consequently less prone to errors
- Math expressions in caption are not in math environment.
- In each row should be `n-1` ampersands, where `n` number of defined columns.
- Package `hyperref` should be loaded last.
- Correcting aforementioned, result when used `article` documentclass is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=normal,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
%\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell,   % new
            multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{lll lll lll lll ll}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
\makecell[l]{$\rho$\\ (g/cm$^3$)}
    & \makecell[l]{$E_1$\\ (MPa)}~~ % ~ added that length of cell content is sufficient long
        & \makecell[l]{$E_2$\\ (MPa)}
            & $\nu_{1_2}$
                & $\nu_{2_3}$
                    & \makecell[l]{$G_{12}$\\ (MPa)}
                       & \makecell[l]{$G_{2_3}$\\ (MPa)}
                            & \makecell[l]{$\sigma_{1_T}$\\ (MPa)}
                                & \makecell[l]{$\sigma_1, C$\\ (MPa)}
                                    & \makecell[l]{$\sigma_2, T$\\ (MPa)}
                                        & \makecell[l]{$\sigma_2, C$\\ (MPa)}
                                            & \makecell[l]{$\tau_{1_2}$\\ (MPa)}
                                                & \makecell[l]{$\tau_{2_3}$\\ (MPa)}
                                                    & \makecell[l]{$U_{1}, T$\\ (N/mm)} \\
    \hline
1.22    & 140000    & 9000  & 0.28 & 0.49 & 5400    & 5400  & 2570  & 1570  & 63.4  & 266   & 95.8  & 95.8  & 12.5  \\
         &          &       &      &      &         &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
         &          &       &      &      &         &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Mechanical property of the carbon fiber/epoxy composite material. Variable $\rho$ is mass density, $E_i$, $\nu_{ij}$, $G_{ij}$, and $\tau_{ij}$ are Young's modulus, Poisson's ratio, shear modulus, and shear strength in corresponding directions; $\sigma_i,T/C$ and $U_i,T/C$ are tensile/compressive strengths in the corresponding directions \cite{liu2014failure}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Using more advanced table package `tabularray` with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx` (both loads corresponding packages), `\small` font size in table, table can be written without use `adjustbox` environment and better vertical spacing of cells' contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=normal,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
%\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\small
\begin{tblr}{colsep  = {3pt},
             colspec = {l X[1.1,c, si={table-format=6}] X[c, si={table-format=4}] 
                        *{2}{X[0.7,c,si={table-format=1.2}]} 
                        *{4}{X[c, si={table-format=5}]} X[c, si={table-format=2.1}]   X[c, si={table-format=3}]    
                        *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=2.1}]}},
             row{1}  = {guard, mode=math, c, bg=gray!30},
             row{2}  = {guard, c, bg=gray!30}
             }
    \toprule
\rho    & E_1       & E_2   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    \nu_{12}
                                    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    \nu_{23}
                                             & G_{12}
                                                    & G_{23} 
                                                            &\sigma_{1_T} 
                                                                    & \sigma_1  
                                                                            & \sigma_2, T 
                                                                                    & \sigma_2, C 
                                                                                            & \tau_{1_2}
                                                                                                    &\tau_{2_3} 
                                                                                                            & U_{1}, T  \\
(\unit{g/cm^3})
        & (MPa)     & (MPa) &       &       & (MPa) & (MPa) & (MPa) & (MPa) & (MPa) & (MPa) & (MPa) & (MPa) & (N/mm)    \\
    \midrule
1.22    & 140000    & 9000  & 0.28 & 0.49   & 5400  & 5400  & 2570  & 1570  & 63.4  & 266   & 95.8  & 95.8  & 12.5      \\
        &           &       &      &        &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &           \\
        &           &       &      &        &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Mechanical property of the carbon fiber/epoxy composite material. Variable $\rho$ is mass density, $E_i$, $\nu_{ij}$, $G_{ij}$, and $\tau_{ij}$ are Young's modulus, Poisson's ratio, shear modulus, and shear strength in corresponding directions; $\sigma_i,T/C$ and $U_i,T/C$ are tensile/compressive strengths in the corresponding directions \cite{liu2014failure}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was great! Thank you so much! Sorry the original code was such a mess, I'm still getting the hang of things.